# Redirecting compiler output to the Win32 program

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, stdout, redirect

Well I've searched for this but obviously found pure explanations and examples for objects in C#, my solution is on C++.
I've a gcc compiler, to which i send command to compile my program (invoke it as a process with a parameters) I need to catch the output and show it in my Win32 written on C++ program.
How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

In C/C++, this is usually done with "popen"

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b(VS.71).aspx
(Windows example, but popen is generally portable)